# Python local client can't connect to Kafka container docker

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

I am attempting to create a basic example with Kafka. I have set up Kafka and Zookeeper using Docker and I am using a local client (using python-kafka) to connect to Kafka, but it did not work

**My docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
  
  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
```

**My producer**:

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:29092'], 
                         api_version = (0,10,2),
                         value_serializer=lambda x: 
                         dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

producer.send('demo_test', value={'surnasdasdame':'parasdasdmar'})
producer.flush()
```

**Errors**:
[image]

Can you give me some solutions?
Thank you guys!

Comment: Please post the error as text not a screenshot.

Comment: Either 1) The container failed to start 2) Your ports list should be 29092:29092 so python can connect properly